# Manually installed go, auto-update in conflict

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, ppa, golang

I have this version of go installed:

```
$ go version
go version go1.10.3 linux/amd64
```

My sources list contains:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gophers-ubuntu-archive-bionic.list
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gophers/archive/ubuntu bionic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gophers/archive/ubuntu bionic main
```

When I do any package updates, I see:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  golang-1.10-go
After this operation, 17.4 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 

(Reading database ... 377323 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../golang-1.10-go_1.10.4-2ubuntu1~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking golang-1.10-go (1.10.4-2ubuntu1~18.04.1) over (1.10.1-1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/golang-1.10-go_1.10.4-2ubuntu1~18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/go-1.10/src', which is also in package golang-1.10-race-detector-runtime 0.0+svn285455-0ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/golang-1.10-go_1.10.4-2ubuntu1~18.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What is going wrong, what is misconfigured, and how can I make the update succeed?

Answer (score 1):

remove package:

```
sudo apt-get remove golang-go
```

remove deps:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove golang-go
```

remove data and config:

```
sudo apt-get purge golang-go
```

then follow the install instructions at [golang.org](https://golang.org/)